# Codeigniter SHA1 Query

Tags: php, codeigniter, sha1

Why is my password not being inserted into the DB

**Model:**

```
function addUser($userData = NULL, $passwordHash)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users',$userData,$passwordHash);
        return TRUE;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public function addUser()
    {
        $data['pageTitle'] = 'GA Add User';
        $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
        $this->load->view('_assets/footer');

        $userData = array(
            'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
            'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
            'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE)
        );

        $passwordHash = sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE));

        $this->db->escape($userData);

        $this->user_model->addUser($userData, $passwordHash);

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to [salt your password hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
function addUser($userData = NULL)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users',$userData);
        return TRUE;
    }


public function addUser()
    {

        $userData = array(
            'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
            'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
            'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
            'password'=>sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
        );


        $this->user_model->addUser($userData);


        $data['pageTitle'] = 'GA Add User';
        $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
        $this->load->view('_assets/footer');

    }
```

Added the password to the $userdata array to keep it cleaner. And modified the addUser function. You don't need to escape the data, the DB library will do it for you. NOTICE that you have to load views at the end of the script

Comment: Thanks,  I am able to print_r my $password field and it shows the sha1 but it still will not import 'password'=>$password but userData works fine.  Ideas the varchar length is 200

Comment: By the way, I see little control of the user input there. You should at least check whether the user and password are not blank. And of course, check if username is already taken

Comment: It is just a simple method to get a starting user in the db :)